# How to implement UIView flip and scale animation like iTunes app

Tags: iphone, animation, opengl-es

I need to implement the above animation in OPENGL. But I am confused about the steps required to achieve it(being opengl noob and all that).
I have  code which will flip views of same size, but i dont know how to achieve the scaling effect.

Comment: I am a bit confused after reading your Question, can you please specify whether you want it in OpenGL ES OR obj-C,

Comment: Did you find any solutions how to do flip/zoom animation linke on iTunes?

Comment: Similar to: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11288575/flipscale-transition-like-itunes-on-ipad