# Flip+Scale Transition like iTunes on iPad

Tags: iphone, uiview

I have checked few other posts and found some UIAnimation transitions that kind-of give the solution to do the Flip+Scale transition just like the iTunes app on iPad. However, i do not get exactly the same results. I have tried looping UIView animations but does not work.

Can someone shed some light on this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So i have been working on this and i finally found a solution :)

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.4 delay:0 options:UIViewAnimationOptionBeginFromCurrentState animations:
 ^{
     rect = placeHolderView.frame;

     rect.origin.x += 100;
     rect.origin.y += 70;

     [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
     [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.5];
      placeHolderView.frame = rect;
     [UIView setAnimationTransition:UIViewAnimationTransitionFlipFromRight forView:placeHolderView cache:YES];
     [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.5];
     CGAffineTransform transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(3.0, 3.0);
     placeHolderView.transform = transform;

     [UIView commitAnimations];

     self.view.layer.cornerRadius = 5.0f;
     self.view.clipsToBounds = YES;

 } completion:^(BOOL finished) {

         [UIView setAnimationBeginsFromCurrentState:YES];
         [UIView transitionWithView:placeHolderView duration:0.8 options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionFlipFromRight|UIViewAnimationOptionBeginFromCurrentState animations:
          ^{
              CGAffineTransform transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(10.0, 10.0);
              placeHolderView.transform = transform;
              [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
              [UIView setAnimationTransition:UIViewAnimationTransitionFlipFromRight forView:self.purchaseItemView cache:YES];
              [placeHolderView setAlpha:0.0];
              [self.myMainView setAlpha:1.0];
              [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.8];
              [UIView commitAnimations];



          } completion:nil];

 }
 ];
```

The placeholderView is the view that will be scaled from a small 16x6 image. While myMainView is the view shown after the flip+scale transition is over. Hope that helps anyone looking to implement this :)